# c# parsing string to date. 'yyyyMMddHHmmss.ffffff+zzz'

Tags: c#, datetime, parsing

I want to parse a string to DateTime with ParseExact. The date string in question is this: `20200917073202.500000+060`.

I tried to convert it with:
`DateTime.ParseExact("20200917073202.500000+060", "yyyyMMddHHmmss.ffffff+zzz", null);` but then i get this error:

```
System.FormatException: 'String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.'
```

Is "yyyyMMddHHmmss.ffffff+zzz" the rigth format? The rigth Date from this string should be "17.09.2020 8:32:02".

---

Edit for more Info:

I get this date string out of a WMI query that looks up the last boot up time.
Strange enough, when I run this code via 'WMI code creator' I get this date string: `20200917083202.500000+120`. Here the time is rigth but now a +120 appears at the end. I still dont exactly know what this number means.

Comment: I guess it should be + 60 min. I get this format out of a WMI query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WMI uses the DMTF (Distributed Management Task Force) time format, which supports `UUU`, which is an offset in minutes. C#'s `DateTime` cannot parse this directly. Have a look at [ManagementDateTimeConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.managementdatetimeconverter.todatetime?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1).

`zzz` as used by you is for a `+01:00` style time zone.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you import the namespace (add the so-named package if needed)

```
using System.Management;
```

The task is as simple as that:

```
DateTime dt = ManagementDateTimeConverter.ToDateTime("20200917073202.500000+060");
```